# Session spring mvc

Tags: spring, java-ee

Пользователь переходит по url

```
@RequestMapping(value="/link/{update}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

Если он не авторизован его перебрасывает на страницу логина. Пользователь авторизуется и его редиректит на

```
@RequestMapping(value="/link", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

Эта ссылка без параметра `{update}` и им приходится заново переходить по ссылке `/link/{update}`. Получится если пользователь не авторизован и `{update}` содержится, записать параметр в сессию. После авторизации вытащить сессию если она есть, вытащить параметр от туда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конфигурации параметром `always-use-default-target="false"` будет всегда возвращать на страницу с которой пришёл пользователь после авторизации.